# Correct way to to organize MEAN stack, Node.js, EJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, ejs

I am new to the MEAN stack so apologies in advance if this topic is well-covered.

Assume I am using ejs, and if I click a certain button on the ejs page, it runs some javascript function, and then updates the ejs page accordingly. How would I accomplish this? Where would the function be written? Certainly, not in a script tag?

To ask a more broad question, is this even good practice. Should Angular.js be used somewhere in this MEAN stack? Is it a good idea to have so much application logic inside the <% code %> tags?

I am not seeing many questions on EJS as well? Do most people circumvent the use of EJS/Jade/Hogan when building mean-stack applications?

Comment: EJS is certainly optional and is most likely overkill, especially when you're just learning.   Have you tried to find some boilerplate applications on github?

Comment: *"Should Angular.js be used somewhere in this MEAN stack?"* - If you're not using Angular you're not using MEAN (given that the "A" in "MEAN" stands for "Angular").

Comment: @nnnnnn Hey, I know that A stands for Angular, but I am not understanding where exactly Angular would come into play. If I consider the most simple application that involves both client-side and server-side, it might be something like:

1) I have a button (EJS), with a textfield, and label output
2) if i enter some text and hit the button, i expect the output to change based on some calculated function on the server-side, right
3) so how exactly do i link that button to server-side functions

Comment: You might want to study [this book](https://leanpub.com/mean-machine/read)